# How to create a singleton from within a private classloader?

Tags: java, jaxb, singleton, classloader

I have a Java class that gets instantiated by a third-party application as an extension.  That is, as per the 3rd party software design, customers like us register our Java class to their application and their application will install it to execute custom logic at the right place and time.

Our custom Java class needs to marshal and unmarshal XML, for which it uses JAXB.  It therefore needs a JAXB context.

I naively called `JAXBContext.newInstance(MyClass.class)` on every call and not-so-quickly discovered that that's a well known recipe for a memory leak.  The common prescription is to make one (or at most only a few) JAXB contexts to share among your whole application.

Fine, except the third party application that invokes my class makes each invocation on a new ClassLoader instance that is private to that invocation.

So, even if I put the `JAXBContext` in a `static` field or `static HashMap<>`, it would still be private to the invocation!

#### QUESTION

How can I, in a class that is instantiated from a private ClassLoader instance, create a singleton to be shared across the JVM?

I am thinking along two possible lines, but I'd like advice on how to make either of them work or any completely different approach anyone has.

The three ideas I had were:

1. Find somewhere in a JVM class where I could write an object.  E.g., if `System.setProperty` could write instance of `Object` instead of just `String`, the idea would be to create the JAXB context and put it in a property, since it is sure that `System` will already have been instantiated and that the custom classloader instance would inherit it.  But `System.setProperty` does not take an `Object` value, so I don't know a practical way to do this.
2. Somehow force a class to load on the parent or root classloader where I could store by JAXB context.  I don't know how to do this.
3. Use a ThreadLocal to store the JAXBContexts.  I don't think each invocation is a brand new thread (they're probably reused from a thread pool), so this could maybe be the way to limit my contexts.  But how to create the ThreadLocal variable so its shared across the instances?  It seems like this leaves me with the same problem.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your code is sandboxed with in the 3rd party application. So using `static` or `ThreadLocal` won't help since it will only exist within the same `classloader`, and if that `classloader` is changed... then the context is lost.

The closest solution is to *inject* your context into the application code. This is not the best idea, since it can be affected by outsiders and have unexpected consequences. Do note that this means a value you created in your `classloader` will remain in the application and thus the creating `classloader` will never be garbage collected. There's also the problem of where `JAXB` *jar* comes from. I assume from your code and not the 3rd party. So that jar is loaded each time in a different classloader, so to share an object from there might be a problem and require some proxy.

Honestly there can be so many unforeseen results.

The best idea is to ask the 3rd party to provide you with some API to enable that.

Before continuing, let's see other options:

- Is there a replacement for using `JAXB`? Something that won't present the same memory leak problem.
- Is the memory leak **that** serious? What if there is a temporary memory leak until an API is provided by the 3rd party application.

If you really want to try to *inject* the object, I'd be happy to help. But, from experience, these kinds of things are messy.

Comment: The memory leak is THAT serious.  It runs in the same JVM that, among other things, serves up the login page to the 3rd party app.  If I call this process enough times (about 1600 in my test instance), the login page stops responding.  I need to be able to call this hundreds of thousands of times.

Comment: And not using `JAXB`? A replacement or not marshaling at all? Maybe `Jackson`?

Comment: Not using JAXB is obviously an option, except we need to make a go/no-go decision on the project and I don't have time to rip out JAXB and have that decision be a "go".

Comment: It's your decision. Though I would suggest to converse with other developers or leads for their thoughts on those options. Because I'm not 100% sure that _injecting_ would actually work well. It still needs a POC to make sure, do you have time for that?

Comment: I am working on my own solution.  So, I need promising approaches from someone who knows this stuff well.  Guesses don't really help me right now, but thank you.

Comment: As I have mentioned, I do have some experience with this kind of thing, so I think I can help. If you want, feel free to chat me up.